# «Так же» или «также»? Как правильно написать?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Недавно услышала такой диалог:
*— Мне 35.

— Мне **так**(?)**же**.*
Я бы это слово написала слитно, потому что можно заменить "и". А вы как считаете?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: "Так же [само]" тоже подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*— Мне 35.*

*— Мне **также**. Мне **тоже**.*

Это **союзы-синонимы** со слитным написанием, что можно использовать **при проверке.**

Но лучше выбрать: **Мне ТОже.** Сравнить: Мне **сТОлько же**.  Один и тот же формант ***ТО*** с указательным значением.

Comment: Спасибо!Ваши ответы очень полезны.

Comment: "Так же" (*так же само*) тоже подходит.

Comment: Не надо ничего писать под МОИМИ ответами.  Варианты рассматривайте сами. Фразеология дл вас: набор фраз в ответ на ваши комментарии.

Comment: А ну успокойтесь! Хочу и пишу! Вы упустили второй правильный вариант! Да вам всё равно, как правильно, вам лишь бы ваши неправильные ответы не трогали. Разобраться и всё выяснить вам совсем не хочется! Другие улучшают ответ после таких комментариев, а вам на всё плевать!

Comment: О, вы сегодня резкий!  И это только в начале дня, что же дальше-то будет.  Поэтому до свидания.

Comment: В ответ на вашу резкость. На резкость всегда отвечаю с ещё большей резкостью. Так что не советую так грубо писать.

Comment: Хорошо)) А можно ничего не писать, вы позволите?

Comment: А вы можете писать "не согласна, потому что" или "согласна, сейчас подправлю"? Почему игнор? Это самое ужасное. Прежде всего за это надо ставить дизлайк.

Comment: Если надо, то ставьте. Тогда моя репутация уменьшится на два балла.

Comment: Это не выход. Вы считаете, что это хорошо? Что это правильно? Это, вообще-то, очень обидно, обиднее всего. Ведь стараешься, когда вам объясняешь. Пусть говорят, плюну-ка на всё с высокой колокольни...

Comment: Извините, я не хотела вас расстраивать. Но если вы видите другой вариант, то сами напишите ответ. Я же обычно не возвращаюсь к уже пройденным темам, есть и другие вопросы  Ну зачем вам меня-то обучать и воспитывать.

Comment: Очень расстраивали, когда очень много писал и всё зря. Но здесь не критика, а к вашему сведению. Надо, чтобы вы научились слышать других и исправлять.

Comment: Я слышу все разумное, что мне говорят. Помните тургеневского Базарова: — Вы не признаете никаких авторитетов? Не верите им? — Да зачем же я стану их признавать? И чему я буду верить? Мне скажут ДЕЛО, я соглашаюсь, вот и все.   Вот когда будете говорить дело, тогда я буду вас слушать.

Comment: Вы ни на что не реагируете! Вы всегда просто отмахиваетесь от всего, называя критикой. Если не согласны, то говорите и аргументируйте. Вы никакие аргументы не слышите. Буквально никакие. Это ужасно!

Comment: Если я вам "ужасно"  не нравлюсь, но  зачем вы со мной разговариваете?  Какой в этом ваш личный интерес?  Критику я быстро сканирую своим сознанием, и сознание говорит мне: ничего стоящего, нечего и время тратить.  Я и не трачу, не аргументирую и не пытаюсь вас в чем-либо убедить. Зачем? Какой здесь может быть мой личный интерес?

Comment: Ужасно вот это, а не ужасно не нравитесь. Чтобы вы стали лучше и умнее. Так не надо сканировать. Надо делить на правильное и неправильное, а не на стоящее и нестоящее. Вы считаете нестоящим всё, что против вас. Так не пойдёт. Интерес может быть в том, чтобы защитить свой ответ. Но вы не сможете, потому что против правды не попрёшь. Говорю не своё мнение (что кажется), а точную информацию.